# Template Variable Already in Use?

Tags: templating

I am brand new to craft and have loved it so far.  Only area that I'm having a hard time understanding is why I cannot use my template variables in my templates.

I am routing `news/` to an action which then uses the `renderTemplate()` method to do just that...render the template.  The result is sent to the browser but it is accompanied by the following php error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class Craft\WassermanNewsVaraible, because the name 
is already in use in /usr/share/nginx/craft/plugins/myPlugin/variables/MyPluginVariable.php on line 5
```

So that tells me that the class is obviously already declared somewhere.  If so how can I access it?  I am currently trying to access it as the documentation describes and is shown below:

```
{% for item in craft.myPlugin.myMethod() %}
  <div>
   Test
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my template variable class which is in myPlugin/variables/

```
namespace Craft;

class MyPluginVaraible
{
    public function myMethod(){
        craft()->myPlugin->myMethod(); //which is in the service
    }
}
```

Is there a difference between how templates are rendered via controllers as opposed to the regular behavior?  I saw that the method had a second parameter however I still could not insatiate my template variables to pass that way as it was still already declared somewhere.

I've been banging away at this one for a while.  Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyPlugin`Varaible` Note the spelling of the highlighted word...